# Apache storm 2 java process for each worker process

Tags: java, apache-storm

When I run `ps aux | grep java` on my machine which is running a storm topology, I can see 2 Java processes running.

```
ps -ef | grep java | grep "storm"
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
test-3p-s+ 10857 10661  0 Apr12 ?        1-02:21:25 java -server -Ddaemon.name=supervisor -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/usr/share/apache-storm -Dstorm.log.dir=/usr/share/apache-storm/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/kryo-3.0.3.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/disruptor-3.3.2.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/storm-rename-hack-1.0.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/clojure-1.7.0.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/conf -Xmx2048m -Dlogfile.name=supervisor.log -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/usr/share/apache-storm/log4j2/cluster.xml org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor
test-3p-s+ 16121 10857  0 Oct13 ?        00:11:31 java -cp /usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/kryo-3.0.3.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/disruptor-3.3.2.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/storm-rename-hack-1.0.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/clojure-1.7.0.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/conf:/var/lib/apache-storm/supervisor/stormdist/TestTopology-97-1665657576/stormjar.jar -Xmx64m -Dlogfile.name=worker.log -Dstorm.home=/usr/share/apache-storm -Dworkers.artifacts=/usr/share/apache-storm/logs/workers-artifacts -Dstorm.id=TestTopology-97-1665657576 -Dworker.id=3324b1de-e8ce-48e6-b065-3fd1f0659c20 -Dworker.port=6706 -Dstorm.log.dir=/usr/share/apache-storm/logs -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/usr/share/apache-storm/log4j2/worker.xml -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector org.apache.storm.LogWriter java -server -Xmx4g -Xms4g -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=16706 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/var/log/apache-storm/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -Xmx4g -Djava.library.path=/var/lib/apache-storm/supervisor/stormdist/TestTopology-97-1665657576/resources/Linux-amd64:/var/lib/apache-storm/supervisor/stormdist/TestTopology-97-1665657576/resources:/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dlogfile.name=worker.log -Dstorm.home=/usr/share/apache-storm -Dworkers.artifacts=/usr/share/apache-storm/logs/workers-artifacts -Dstorm.conf.file= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.log.dir=/usr/share/apache-storm/logs -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/apache-storm/workers/3324b1de-e8ce-48e6-b065-3fd1f0659c20/tmp -Dlogging.sensitivity=S3 -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/usr/share/apache-storm/log4j2/worker.xml -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector -Dstorm.id=TestTopology-97-1665657576 -Dworker.id=3324b1de-e8ce-48e6-b065-3fd1f0659c20 -Dworker.port=6706 -cp /usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/kryo-3.0.3.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/disruptor-3.3.2.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/storm-rename-hack-1.0.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/clojure-1.7.0.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/conf:/var/lib/apache-storm/supervisor/stormdist/TestTopology-97-1665657576/stormjar.jar org.apache.storm.daemon.worker TestTopology-97-1665657576 b64def27-088a-41ae-95a9-b5195c88bbfa 6706 3324b1de-e8ce-48e6-b065-3fd1f0659c20
test-3p-s+ 16158 16121 87 Oct13 ?        15-13:11:48 java -server -Xmx4g -Xms4g -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=16706 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/var/log/apache-storm/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -Xmx4g -Djava.library.path=/var/lib/apache-storm/supervisor/stormdist/TestTopology-97-1665657576/resources/Linux-amd64:/var/lib/apache-storm/supervisor/stormdist/TestTopology-97-1665657576/resources:/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dlogfile.name=worker.log -Dstorm.home=/usr/share/apache-storm -Dworkers.artifacts=/usr/share/apache-storm/logs/workers-artifacts -Dstorm.conf.file= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.log.dir=/usr/share/apache-storm/logs -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/apache-storm/workers/3324b1de-e8ce-48e6-b065-3fd1f0659c20/tmp -Dlogging.sensitivity=S3 -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/usr/share/apache-storm/log4j2/worker.xml -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector -Dstorm.id=TestTopology-97-1665657576 -Dworker.id=3324b1de-e8ce-48e6-b065-3fd1f0659c20 -Dworker.port=6706 -cp /usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/kryo-3.0.3.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/disruptor-3.3.2.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/storm-rename-hack-1.0.1.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/lib/clojure-1.7.0.jar:/usr/share/apache-storm/conf:/var/lib/apache-storm/supervisor/stormdist/TestTopology-97-1665657576/stormjar.jar org.apache.storm.daemon.worker TestTopology-97-1665657576 b64def27-088a-41ae-95a9-b5195c88bbfa 6706 3324b1de-e8ce-48e6-b065-3fd1f0659c20
```

It seems all the 3 java process are related as parent client, as PPID of a pid is same as pid of previous java process. But can some please explain:

1. How these processes are spawned? (using `java.lang.Process` API?)
2. Who is monitoring whom?
3. Why do we need the second Java process?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a partial answer. In your terminal, you can see basically 3 processes:

1. The `Supervisor` - this is the overarching storm process that is responsible for the coordinations of `LogWriters` and `Workers.` So it basically starts and kills them and it has an own logfile. You can aso configure, of how many Workers you want to spawn (=slots)
2. The `LogWriter`: This seems to be responsible for generating the log - but I am really not sure why one need a separate JVM for that.
3. The `Worker` - this is executing one operator (bolt or spout) of a topology. So this is created by the supervisor and lives as long as the topology lives. You could run multiple workers in parallel.

I am also not sure why they designed it that way - so please have a look at my separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72001598/why-does-apache-storm-instantiate-a-jvm-for-every-slot) on that. For the exact time & call of spawning, you'll need to dig through their implementation - I couldn't identify the relevant code on a first glimpse - but would be happy if you could share your results.

Comment: it might be a naming convention issue. https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/LogWriter.java is the source code, i will go through and come back